# BSD grep "?" wildcard alternative for GNU

Tags: macos, ubuntu, grep

I have a grep command that works on my Mac with BSD grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD which I'm using to search a very long, single-line bash var:

`echo $MY_VAR | grep -Eo s3.+?model`

On Ubuntu with GNU grep 2.25, the `?` wildcard doesn't seem to work. It doesn't stop at the first occurrence of "model".

Would someone please show me how to get this same match in Ubuntu? Open to either changing the pattern or installing a different/updated grep.

Not going to list the million patterns I've tried so far, but been struggling for a while with this.

**Edit:** The following seems to work since there's a "," after "model", but looks pretty ugly:

`egrep -o 's3.*model' | grep -o '^[^,]*'`

Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I don't have any perl or ruby experience though, mostly a python/C programmer. Is it at all possible to actually just install BSD grep on ubuntu?

Comment: Try `grep -Po s3.+?model`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked, thank you!!!

Comment: @EdMorton no idea.. using a 2017 MBP with macOS Mojave 10.14.2 (18C54) and the default grep that it comes with which is apparently BSD grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex option `P` with GNU `grep`, it also allows the use of non-greedy quantifiers:

```
echo $MY_VAR | grep -Po s3.+?model
                     ^
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/j85099):

```
MY_VAR="s3://model/;s3://another/model"
echo $MY_VAR | grep -Po 's3.+?model'
# => s3://model
#    s3://another/model
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from Wiktor's example and considering your comment and code related to commas, it sounds like this is what you want with any grep that has a `-E` for EREs:

```
$ MY_VAR='s3://model/,s3://another/model'
$ echo "$MY_VAR" | grep -Eo 's3[^,]+model'
s3://model
s3://another/model
```